# Is there a way to show registered handlers or listeners in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, handler

I'm trying to debug a "handler...was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list" issue.

There are `--list-host`, `--list-tags`, and `--list-tags` options, but nothing for listing registered handlers.  I've run ansible-playbook with the "debug" strategy and with `-vvvv`, but neither of those seem to provide any insight.  I don't see any "magic" variables that might contain this information.

Is there any way to show/dump these handlers and/or listeners?

Comment: Post the code of the handler and of the task that notifies it.

Comment: I tried to fix the same problem. Finally found out that indention of `listen:` was wrong in the handler. (But without generating any error. No idea why this is possible.). Maybe this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Is there any way to show/dump these handlers and/or listeners?"***

A: No. In [*ansible-playbook*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html), there is no such option (similar to --list-host, --list-tags, ...) to show/dump handlers and/or listeners.

---

Note: You can write a playbook and list the handlers on your own. For example, the playbook below reads the file from the variable *pb_file* and writes the lists of the handlers in each play

```yaml
shell> cat list-handlers.yml
- name: List handlers
  hosts: localhost

  vars:

    pb_file: "{{ pb_file|default('playbook.yml') }}"
    pb_dict: "{{ lookup('file', pb_file)|from_yaml }}"
    pb_handlers: "{{ dict(pb_dict|json_query('[].[name,handlers[].name]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |

          playbook: {{ pb_file }}

          {% for play,handlers in pb_handlers.items() %}
          play {{ '#' }}{{ loop.index }} {{ play }}
              HANDLERS: {{ handlers|d([], true)|join(', ') }}

          {% endfor %}
          
      when: pb_file is exists
```

Given the playbook below for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- name: Play1 test handlers
  hosts: target1,target2

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: Notify handler1
      changed_when: true
      notify: handler1
    - debug:
        msg: Notify handler2
      changed_when: true
      notify: handler2

  handlers:

    - name: handler1
      debug:
        msg: Run handler1
    - name: handler2
      debug:
        msg: Run handler2

- name: Play2 test handlers
  hosts: target1,target2

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Play2
```

List the handlers

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook list-handlers.yml -e pb_file=pb.yml

PLAY [List handlers] *****************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |2-
  
    playbook: pb.yml
  
    play #1 Play1 test handlers
        HANDLERS: handler1, handler2
  
    play #2 Play2 test handlers
        HANDLERS:

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```